# How do I get the number of rows of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r

After reading a dataset:

```
dataset <- read.csv("forR.csv")
```

- How can I get R to give me the number of cases it contains?
- Also, will the returned value include of exclude cases omitted with `na.omit(dataset)`?

Comment: I also recommend taking a look at `str()` as it provides other useful details about your object. Can often explain why a column isn't behaving as it should (factor instead of numeric, etc).

Comment: Please read the R guide of Owen first (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Owen-TheRGuide.pdf), and if possible, Introduction to R (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf). Both are on the official website of R. You're incredibly lucky you actually get an answer. On the r-help list one would redirect you to the manual in less elegant terms. No offense meant.

Comment: @Joris - Point taken (without offence), but it was my impression that SE sites were designed to foster problem/solution learning in a way not afforded by manuals. Additionally, this question will now be available for other beginners. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: If you're looking for pure code solutions, stackoverflow might be more appropriate. Although, all the R gurus present @ SO are also here (not counting myself). :)

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that this question will be helpful for other beginners, *especially* if they don't skim the manual.  They will just create a duplicate question.

Comment: @JorisMeys: thanks for the link to the R guide.. hadn't come across that yet in my learning of R and it's exactly what I'd been looking for.

Comment: And, four years later, this is the second hit I got on Google trying to find an answer to this question. No need for me to create a duplicate (@JoshuaUlrich).

Comment: @Richard Just noticed that (6 years on) this question has 100 upvotes and is consequently well within the top 0.1% of questions on the site. I find this very interesting.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

`dataset` will be a data frame. As I don't have `forR.csv`, I'll make up a small data frame for illustration:

```
set.seed(1)
dataset <- data.frame(A = sample(c(NA, 1:100), 1000, rep = TRUE),
                      B = rnorm(1000))

> head(dataset)
   A           B
1 26  0.07730312
2 37 -0.29686864
3 57 -1.18324224
4 91  0.01129269
5 20  0.99160104
6 90  1.59396745
```

To get the number of cases, count the number of rows using `nrow()` or `NROW()`:

```
> nrow(dataset)
[1] 1000
> NROW(dataset)
[1] 1000
```

To count the data after omitting the `NA`, use the same tools, but wrap `dataset` in `na.omit()`:

```
> NROW(na.omit(dataset))
[1] 993
```

The difference between `NROW()` and `NCOL()` and their lowercase variants (`ncol()` and `nrow()`) is that the lowercase versions will only work for objects that have dimensions (arrays, matrices, data frames). The uppercase versions will work with vectors, which are treated as if they were a 1 column matrix, and are robust if you end up subsetting your data such that R drops an empty dimension.

Alternatively, use `complete.cases()` and `sum` it (`complete.cases()` returns a logical vector [`TRUE` or `FALSE`] indicating if any observations are `NA` for any rows.

```
> sum(complete.cases(dataset))
[1] 993
```

Answer (score 40):

Briefly:

1. Run `dim(dataset)` to retrieve both *n* and *k*, you can also use `nrow(df)` and `ncol(df)` (and even `NROW(df)` and `NCOL(df)` -- variants are needed for other types too).
2. If you transform e.g. via `dataset <- na.omit(dataset)`, then the cases are gone and are not counted.  But if you do *e.g.* `summary(dataset)` the NA cases are accounted for.